# Best way to represent a tree of unknown depth of the same type of object in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tree

The obvious answer here is to have a single class representing the object, then a reference to the parent object if there is one. The query across the tree would be to start at a given node of the tree and return all parent objects of that node. Each node will have only one direct parent node.

Is there a better way to do this computationally or from a software design perspective?

EDIT: Looking for computational complexity improvement suggestions or maintainability suggestions. Memory is not a huge issue here.

Comment: You can also keep an optional array of children that can make the upside-down build easier

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Better computationally" depends entirely on the usage patterns of the tree, e.g. like the difference between linked lists and arrays. How will the tree be traversed, typically? What are the memory requirements?

Comment: The tree will typically be traversed by querying a database for a single node, then finding all parents of that node. There can only be one parent per node. Application will be running on scalable servers so memory isn't the limiting factor here, but rather overall performance/speed to compute.

Comment: Ain't the entire task better suited for the DB itself? Because no matter what your data-structure looks like, once you receive the node from the DB you still have to search for its equivalent in your data-structure, just to then traverse along the `.parent` relations and put them into a list. What kind on DB are we talking about?

Comment: @Thomas a relational one. Not sure what our team's opinion is on stored procs but if there is compelling enough reason to use them I'm sure I can make the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Thomas a relational one. Not sure what our team's opinion is on stored procs but if there is compelling enough reason to use them I'm sure I can make the case.

In a relational DB I would use a [common-table-expression](/questions/tagged/common-table-expression)

```
WITH foo AS   
(  
    -- your start node
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyData AS d
    WHERE d.id = 123

    UNION ALL  

    -- traversing up
    SELECT parent.*
    FROM MyData AS parent
    JOIN foo AS child
      ON parent.id = child.parentId
)
-- selecting the data you want to return from the CTE
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

In JS terms, here a description what the above query does:

```
// initial SELECT
var foo = myData.filter(item => item.id === 123);

// UNION ALL + SELECT with JOIN onto `foo`
for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; ++i) {
  foo.push(...myData.filter(item => item.id === foo[i].parentId));
}

console.log(foo);
```

only that a DB select is way faster and more performant than the Array#filter() in the JS code, but basically they produce the same result; a list of (0 or more) matches

Comment: Wouldn't we have to run a cursor to recursively traverse up the tree for an unknown number of potential parent nodes? I think maybe my explanation of the problem was unclear; each node has only one direct parent, but that parent node can have its own parent node, and so on. Or am I missing something in the SQL here?

Comment: @badpanda I'm fully aware of that. *"Or am I missing something in the SQL here?"* probably this line here `JOIN foo AS child`. Read up about CTEs and if they are available to you. The lower part of the CTE is joining onto the very list it is currently creating and is extending it. It will resolve the hierarchy recursively.

Comment: Ooh, lovely. This is a great response. Thanks for your help!